# GRPC client is not working

Tags: grpc

when i'm running the grpc client i'm getting the following error.my grpc-server is working well ....................................................................................................................................................

```
 mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.grpc.client.MyGrpcClient.java" -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: linux
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.release: ubuntu
[INFO] os.detected.release.version: 14.04
[INFO] os.detected.release.like.ubuntu: true
[INFO] os.detected.release.like.debian: true
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: linux-x86_64
[WARNING] Failed to inject repository session properties.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession.getRepositorySession()Lorg/eclipse/aether/RepositorySystemSession;
        at kr.motd.maven.os.RepositorySessionInjector.injectRepositorySession(RepositorySessionInjector.java:22)
        at kr.motd.maven.os.DetectExtension.injectSession(DetectExtension.java:148)
        at kr.motd.maven.os.DetectExtension.afterProjectsRead(DetectExtension.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building simple-grpc-client 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) @ simple-grpc-client ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.591s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 01 14:50:54 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project simple-grpc-client: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java failed: Invalid classpath scope: tuomas -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project simple-grpc-client: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java failed: Invalid classpath scope: tuomas
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java failed: Invalid classpath scope: tuomas
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid classpath scope: tuomas
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.AbstractExecMojo.collectProjectArtifactsAndClasspath(AbstractExecMojo.java:118)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.addRelevantProjectDependenciesToClasspath(ExecJavaMojo.java:607)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.getClassLoader(ExecJavaMojo.java:528)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:308)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecution
```

I am using maven here.I will be much appreciated if you can help me............

```
here is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2016 Google, Inc.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>grpc-demos</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>simple-grpc-client</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-grpc-server</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

it is taking dependencies from server. i changed it as follows to get dependencies by its own.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2016 Google, Inc.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>grpc-demos</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>simple-grpc-client</artifactId>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--
                      The version of protoc must match protobuf-java. If you don't depend on
                      protobuf-java directly, you will be transitively depending on the
                      protobuf-java version that grpc depends on.
                    -->
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please add your pom.xml so people can help you in your particular situation!

Comment: thank you @V.Momjyan. i have posted my pom.xml

Comment: Still, you have a parent pom.xml which would also be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

well.i've just figured out the problem you have.
i select my maven version from nested one 3.05 to 3.39,and it work out properly.
pay attention,even if you got 3.39 in your terminal when you write`mvn --version`,it doesn't mean that you are using mvn 3.39,you should set it in your settings,and then you are really using maven of a version 3.39.